# Come scrivere paese quando è sottinteso che sia l'Italia

Tags: nouns, capitalization, orthography

Correlativamente al recente concorso pubblicato per assumere 42.101 docenti ordinari e 22.237 docenti di sostegno scrivevo a un collega:

> Oscuro è il futuro di un paese che assume insegnanti di sostegno in misura superiore al 50% di quelli ordinari.

Mi sono poi chiesto se lì 'paese' andasse scritto con la maiuscola o no, essendo sottinteso che il paese cui mi riferivo è l'Italia.

Comment: Non mi pare necessario, in questo contesto. Piuttosto, l'aggiunta di *o meno* è ridondante e, comunque, si dovrebbe dire *o no*.

Comment: A mio parere non è necessario, in quanto il contesto lo chiarisce.

Answer (score 4):

Per quanto dal contesto è chiaro che "paese" si riferisce all'Italia, usare la maiuscola renderebbe l'associazione all'italia inequivocabile (infatti, [l'uso di "Paese" in italiano è diventato solo significativo nel 20° secolo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paese,Paese&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,paese;,c0;.t1;,Paese;,c0)).

Ciò detto, scrivere "Paese" sembra sottendere un livello di patriottismo che sembra stonare col resto del messaggio.

Answer (score 3):

La frase proposta non si presta molto visto che intende applicarsi a qualsiasi paese che soddisfi la condizione menzionata, e non ad un paese specifico, benché sia poi chiaro che il termine implicito di paragone sia l'Italia («Il futuro di un paese che, come l'Italia, …»). Proprio il fatto che si stia facendo implicito riferimento all'Italia rende inutile l'uso della maiuscola in "paese": non può trattarsi di un paesello quello che si vuol paragonare all'Italia, ma piuttosto di un ente nazionale. Ad ogni modo, l'uso della maiuscola in questo caso [potrebbe essere lecito](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_226.html) (anche [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/maiuscole-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/), [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-delle-maiuscole_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) e [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/maiuscola_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/)): in ultimo è una questione di gusti personali.

[Qui](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/uso-maiuscole-minuscole), Luca Serianni e Giovanni Nencioni (Accademia della Crusca) offrono un autorevole punto di vista sull'uso della maiuscola in generale.

Facciamo un altro esempio in cui il paese che si sottintende sia proprio l'Italia:

```
«Quanto vale l'arte in Italia? Quanto vale l'arte nel Paese?»
```

Questa può rendersi con

```
«Quanto vale l'arte nel Belpaese?»
```

La locuzione "Bel Paese" o il sostantivo "Belpaese" sono [tipicamente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bel-paese/) usati per indicare l'Italia, il «bel paese là dove ’l sì sona».